# limit as $\delta \rightarrow 0 \int_{a + \delta}^{b} f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

$f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, assumed to be Riemann integrable, and we let $\delta > 0$ be given.

Perhaps starting with boundedness may be the right way to go? We know that, since a continuous function on a closed interval attains its max value $M$ and min value $m$:

$m \cdot (b - a - \delta) \leq \int_{a + \delta}^{b} f(x)dx \leq M \cdot (b - a - \delta)$

but I'm unsure of where to go from here!

Comment: Use $\left|\int_{a}^b f(x) \, dx - \int_{a+\delta}^b f(x) \, dx\right| = \left|\int_{a}^{a+\delta} f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant \int_{a}^{a+\delta} |f(x)| \, dx$

Comment: @RRL Thank you! then it would be sufficient to show that the limit as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ of $\int_{a}^{a + \delta} f(x)dx$ is $0$?

Comment: Yes as you are doing with $|f(x)| \leqslant M$.

Comment: Also, if $f$ is continuous, not only is the integral continuous everywhere including the endpoints (which is what you asked), it is also differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Your result holds under the weaker assumption that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and follows from the continuity of the function $F$ given by $F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ this actually implies it is Riemann integerable, we don't need to add the assumption.

Let's use the definition of Riemann integration:

Consider the partition $P=\{x_0=a<x_1<x_2<...x_n= b\}$,

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n}^Nf(x_n)(x_n,x_{n-1})$.

Now consider the partition $P_{\delta}=\{x_0=a+\delta<x_1<x_2<...x_n= b\}$ $\int_{a+\delta}^{b}f(x)dx=lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n}^Nf(x_n)(x_n,x_{n-1})+f(a+\delta)(x_0+\delta)$. Note the extra term at the end comes from the slightly modified partition.

Now if we compare the two partitions, note as $\delta\rightarrow 0$ $P_{\delta}=P$, and we have our result.